# Why gethostbyname(gethostname()); in PHP is giving an IP different from my machine's ip

Tags: php

I have the following php script trying to get current server ip in this case my machine's current ip address but the gethostbyname(gethostname()) is returning a different address i.e http://192.168.56.1/ but my current address from ipconfig is http://192.168.1.111/.

```
$server_ip = gethostbyname(gethostname());
$upload_url = 'http://'.$server_ip.':81/';
echo $upload_url;
```

if i try to get a resource using the ip that the function is returning using a browser it works, but the problem comes when trying to get the same resource from a mobile client(it does not work) but if l change the ip to the one my machine is using on network it fetches the resource ok.
So there is a php script and a mobile client when the app post an image to the server l want to save the url which can be referenced by the mobile client to load  the image using for example Glide lib
so was trying to get the hostnames ip using the above php function ,want to understand why it returns an ip different from the one tht the host is assigned to on the network. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why/how is the ip of the machine php is running on not known (it's surely not variable)? What is it you're actually trying to do, there's mention of a mobile client, so it sounds like you're trying to test something.

Comment: yes its php script that receives an image uploaded from a mobile app, it then saves the image into a folder on the server then inserts the url into the database.So this method $server_ip = gethostbyname(gethostname()); returns something like http://192.168.56.1:81/byro/asa/api/profilepics/IMG_20190513_110403.jpg but the 192.168.56.1 is not the ip of my machine on the network the actual would be http://192.168.1.111:81/byro/asa/api/profilepics/IMG_20190513_110403.jpg..i dont kow if it is getting clearer

Comment: So the PHP script is running on the machine which you are describing as "my machine", is that correct? You haven't actually stated that explicitly. Please confirm that's what you mean. N.B. It's possible for a device to have more than one IP address (e.g. if it has both ethernet and wireless connections active).

Comment: just storing `/byro/...` is probably going to solve your problem (I.e. don't store the hostname at all) - please edit the question to make it clear what is talking to what etc. (It shouldn't be necessary to read any comments for a reader to understand the question/problem).

Comment: ooh yes absolutely "my machine" refers to the where the script is running using XAMPP..thanks for the advice on the possibility of multiple addresses

Answer (score 0):

`gethostbyname(gethostname())` can return an IP differrent from your 'machine IP'. What do I mean here? 
Example: If you are using VPN tunnel to direct your machine's traffic. Your machine is going to have two different IPs. by default `gethostbyname(gethostname())` will return your IP as seen via VPN.